# Failed to resolve: firebase-database-15.0.0. I fix this error and get another one

Tags: android, firebase, android-studio, firebase-realtime-database

I add implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.5' to my dependencies and then get the error:
Warning: The app gradle file must have a dependency on com.google.firebase:firebase-core for Firebase services to work as intended.
[My gradle script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ghj9k.png)

Comment: Please share your gradle file

Comment: I looked at that before posting but it did not help

Answer (score 0):

> You have to explicitly add the core dependency for Firebase services
>   to work

add the following line to your app gradle file

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.6'
```

if you still get the warning, make sure you are using core updated version

Comment: it worked, thank you!